# Opening a closed Polygon in Openlayers to continue Drawing - Undo functionality

Tags: openlayers

Before undo

[image: Before Undo]

After Undo

[image]

I am trying to create an undo functionality with Openlayers where I can open a drawing completed Polygon and continue drawing the shape again.
Not sure how to implement the undo functionality for each points of a polygon.

Could you please help me to find a solution for this?

I have seen undo functionality from some third party library using Openlayers, in which the whole shape will be deleted from map when we do the undo.
Also,I have seen modify functionality in Openlayers where I can add more points to the existing shape and change the structure of shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done by using the `geometryFunction` option in the interaction to use the geometry of an existing feature instead of starting a new one.  The rendering of the sketch lines doesn't work as expected so they would need to be handled by a style function.  If you wanted to use both draw and modify interactions when one starts/ends you might need to disable/re-enable the other.

```js
  var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
  var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
  var width = 3;

  var drawStyles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width + 2
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: blue,
        width: width
      })
    })
  ];

  var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var source = new ol.source.Vector();
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#ffcc33'
        })
      })
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Polygon',
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
      if (geometry) {
        if (coordinates[0].length) {
          // Add a closing coordinate to match the first
          geometry.setCoordinates([coordinates[0].concat([coordinates[0][0]])]);
        } else {
          geometry.setCoordinates([]);
        }
      } else {
        var existing = source.getFeatures()[0];
        if (existing) {
          source.removeFeature(existing);
          geometry = existing.getGeometry();
          coordinates[0] = geometry.getCoordinates()[0].slice(0,-2).concat([coordinates[0][0]]);
          geometry.setCoordinates([coordinates[0].concat([coordinates[0][0]])]);
        } else {
          geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates);
        }
      }
      return geometry;
    },
    style: function(feature) {
      if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Polygon') {
        var sketchLine = new ol.geom.LineString(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].slice(0,-1));
        drawStyles[1].setGeometry(sketchLine);
        drawStyles[2].setGeometry(sketchLine);
        return drawStyles;
      } else {
        return pointStyle;
      }
    }
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

The simplest way to set an undo on an active draw interaction is to call `removeLastPoint()` when a key such as Esc is hit.  It will work with the code I used in a real page, but the keydown listener doesn't work inside a stackoverflow runnable snippet

```
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27)
      draw.removeLastPoint();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will try this for my requirement and update you the result

Comment: I tried this locally and seems like last two points cannot be removed as part of the undo,Could you please help me to remove the last two points also?

Comment: Hi Mike,
Also I am looking for a solution to perform the undo on pressing a button.Each time when I press the button , each points of the polygon should go back as similar to the undo

Comment: Just call `draw.removeLastPoint();`  I've added to my answer.

Comment: @Thank you Mike
Is there any way to open the closed polygon by just doing a keypress?

Comment: Just to give more clarity to the above comment. Suppose if the user accidentally closed a polygon and want to reopen that with a short cut key.

Comment: I found a solution to this based on your comments and I have posted that below as another answer

Answer (score 0):

@Mike, I found another way to do this by adding a new prototype function to the Draw interaction.Please find the code below,

```
 ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.reStart = function (selectedFeature) {
    this.abortDrawing_();
    var coordinates, sketchLineGeom;
    var geometry = selectedFeature.getGeometry();
    var selectedCoordinates = geometry.getCoordinates()[0];
    this.sketchFeature_ = this.sketchFeature_?this.sketchFeature_:selectedFeature;
    coordinates = selectedCoordinates;
    if (this.mode_ === ol.interaction.Draw.Mode_.POLYGON) {  
    this.sketchCoords_ =  [coordinates.slice(0,-1)];  
        var last = coordinates[coordinates.length-2];
        this.finishCoordinate_ = last.slice()[0];
        this.sketchCoords_[0].push(last.slice());
        sketchLineGeom = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
        this.sketchLine_=new ol.Feature(sketchLineGeom);
        this.geometryFunction_(this.sketchCoords_, geometry);
        this.sketchLineCoords_ = this.sketchCoords_[0];
      }
      if (coordinates.length === 0) {
        this.finishCoordinate_ = null;
      }
      this.updateSketchFeatures_();
      this.dispatchEvent(new ol.interaction.Draw.Event(
      ol.interaction.DrawEventType.DRAWSTART, this.sketchFeature_));
      };
```

Comment: We need to pass the relevant feature as an argument and rest of the actions will be done by that function.

Comment: It isn't using public API methods it will only work with a debug or custom build and probably won't work if you need to move to a more recent version.

Comment: @Mike, Can I make this change to the latest Openlayers library and make a pull request. This is a new functionality right?